# How i can sent a zip directory to python server?

Tags: java, android

I am a rookie in android and now i encounter with such issue. I need sent a zip directory to the phyton server and the first i have tried make it with help of `MultipartEntity`, but it is use a `HttpClient` and `HttpPost` which don't support now with sdk 23 and depricate now.

And i figure out that i can use `OkHttp` instead. I found some samples, but they clear up how sent `json` file. [There is](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes) loads of samples but no one how to sent a dir...

Who have a sample how to sent a zip directory, help me please...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
HttpClient http = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("MyApp");
HttpPost m = new HttpPost("http://url-to-your-python-server");

m.setEntity(new FileEntity(new File("path-to-zip-file"), "application/octet-stream"));

HttpResponse response = http.execute(m);
```

Comment: Thanks!  i should test it, and say you if it is will be work) But now i noticed that `HttpClient` , `HttpPost`,  `HttpResponse` are deprecated...

Comment: You can use *HttpURLConnection* class then